# Class App\Http\Controllers\CreateTagRequest does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error when submit value.

Here is my controller:

```
   { namespace App\Http\Controllers;

     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use App\Tag;
     use App\Http\Requests\Tags\CreateTagsRequest;
     use App\Http\Requests\Tags\UpdateTagsRequest;
  }
```

This is TagRequest:

```
<?php

      namespace App\Http\Requests\Tags;

      use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


      class CreateTagsRequest extends FormRequest
      {
   
        public function authorize()
       {
        return true;
       }

       public function rules()
        {
           return [
              'name'=>'required|unique:tags'
                   ];
        }
}
```

Comment: What's with those brackets in your "controller"? Can we see the method where you actually use `CreateTagsRequest`?

Comment: Your subject mentions `CreateTagRequest` (vs. `CreateTagsRequest`) is that a typo?

Comment: hello, can u show ur full controller so we can see where the problem at? and whats error did u getting. please tell more specific

Comment: public function store(CreateTagsRequest $request)
    {
       
        Tag::create([
            'name'=>$request->name

        ]);

        session()->flash('success','Tag created successfully.');
        
        return redirect(route('tags.index'));
    }

Comment: edit it on your post maybe

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload` to see if that fixes it

Comment: its working now..when i have cleared my cache.